How do I solve this on CNN on real image files-creating the model?
I'm encountering a ValueError in my Keras model. I'm trying to load a pre-trained model using load_model, but I'm getting the error ValueError: Kernel shape must have the same length as input. I've specified the input shape (130, 130, 3), but the error persists. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Keras model accepts batches, you may need to add a dimension to your input data, data_in =data_in[None, ...]

Hello zain i added a dimension as u said ,I'm getting an error saying data_in is not defined

Hi Abby, data_in is your input data, the one with the shape of(130, 130, 3). Replace data_in with your own variable name.

Pre-trained models are typically trained on images of size (224, 224), so
it's important to match that input size when using these models. If you're
providing images of size (130, 130), the model may not work properly. I
recommend resizing your images to the original size expected by the model
(224, 224) and trying again. Let me know if you're still
encountering any issues.
